# ionic: double curly braces "{{" not evaluated

Tags: html, angularjs, web, ionic-framework

I have an HTML file, in which i'm trying to display a variable from a controller, like so:

```
<script src="js/app.js"></script>
<script src="js/controllers.js"></script>
<script src="js/services.js"></script>
<body ng-app="starter">
      <ion-pane>

          <ion-content ng-controller="ListCtr”>
              {{var}}      <!-- this is not evaluated! -->
          </ion-content>

      </ion-pane>
  </body>
```

The output is plainly: `{{scope.var}}`
instead of `Hello!`

The `controllers.js` file:

```
angular.module('starter.controllers', [])

.controller('DashCtrl', function($scope) {})

.controller('ChatsCtrl', function($scope, Chats) {

            $scope.chats = Chats.all();
            $scope.remove = function(chat) {
            Chats.remove(chat);
            }
            })

.controller('ChatDetailCtrl', function($scope, $stateParams, Chats) {
            $scope.chat = Chats.get($stateParams.chatId);
            })

.controller('AccountCtrl', function($scope) {
            $scope.settings = {
            enableFriends: true
            };
            })


<!-- ** This the controller, which has the referenced var ** -->
.controller('ListCtr', function ($scope) {
            $scope.var = "Hello!";
            })
;
```

Can anyone please point out what i'm doing wrong??

Comment: Check your console, are you getting any errors? Is the start module defined?

Comment: replace with {{var}}..

Comment: Given your `<script>` tags you'll probably want to include `angular.js` as well.

Comment: It's resolved! it was due to a missing bracket in the controller definition.

Comment: thank you all for your time

Answer (score 1):

You are binding `var` to `$scope` then you can reference it directly in corresponding view. Remove `scope` in html

```
 <ion-content ng-controller="ListCtr”>
    {{var}}
 </ion-content>
```

Comment: Sorry. That was a mistake in my question. Edited it now. I AM using just `{{var}}`, but it still does not evaluate the `var`.

Comment: @Alterecho can you provide a working demo to reproduce this error ? See this [demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/RpiViz71M7TOOWAYD5U8?p=preview), two way binding works perfectly.

Comment: Since this is ionic, it has a lot of dependencies, is it fine if i share with you a google drive link?

Comment: @Alterecho here is a [working ionic demo](http://codepen.io/sondn2010/pen/OPbJmq) you can start with. If it's still too complicated, then you can share me with google drive.

Comment: It's resolved! it was due to a missing bracket in the controller definition.